# click event of WindowsFormsControlLibrary button in MFC Dialog based app

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, mfc

I'm using some `Windows Forms Control Library` elements in my app.

My question is:

How to perform button click event which this element comes from Windows Forms Control Library?

So, I can get `*library*` textbox value in `ProgramDlg.cpp` file like this:

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    AfxMessageBox(CString(m_ctrl1.GetControl()->textBox1->Text));
    // m_ctrl1.GetControl()->button1->Click(); 
    // how can I write this above line to perform click event?
}
```

I defined `m_ctrl1` in `ProgramDlg.h`:

```
// .... 
public:
        CMFCApplication1Dlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);  // standard constructor
        // Data member for the .NET User Control:
        CWinFormsControl<WindowsFormsControlLibrary1::UserControl1> m_ctrl1;
// ....
```

p.s sorry for my bad english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by visiting [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af8w7d7d.aspx).

Hope to be useful for other developers.